# root space still low after I mounted a 500G disk to /data and moved files in

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk-usage

I'm using a Cloud server:

```
Architecture: x86_64
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
```

In the beginning, I only had one 40G disk, which mounted on `/`, as my application and the
running docker image files very soon. There's not too much space left.

I added another 500G data disk: `/dev/sdb` with `primary partition` and
formatted it with: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb`, finally mounted it to `/data`，Then I transfered over 20G files(include moved docker to `/data/docker` by following [link](https://mrkandreev.name/snippets/how_to_move_docker_data_to_another_location/)), I was expecting to get over 50% space to be released.

This is the `df -m` now:

```
root@iot-message-2001:/# df -m
Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                7961     0      7961   0% /dev
tmpfs               1601     2      1600   1% /run
/dev/sda1          40253 36235      2262  95% /
tmpfs               8005     1      8005   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5     0         5   0% /run/lock
tmpfs               8005     0      8005   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb          502941 30092    447233   7% /data
overlay           502941 30092    447233   7% /data/docker/overlay2/24dc450509b6e137b48776f3afb1f9a3cc30c485254e2104cbf9bf2b175ac0fd/merged
overlay           502941 30092    447233   7% /data/docker/overlay2/8a366c978be56388958b12286cb0c38f4321834a963de95acdc8e852ff29fc7b/merged
shm                   64     0        64   0% /data/docker/containers/ab84a181f9fbfddc9b1bb83f57431661a9cef548e1f31d86a8548e017a45d50f/mounts/shm
overlay           502941 30092    447233   7% /data/docker/overlay2/cb3fa68ae2b92d02ddaea1729a7821c9bc89531dc6f24da6b0c624f26f266b69/merged
shm                   64     0        64   0% /data/docker/containers/4133a58d1b5d62188d8a3c3c67eebcc02c4463dabe05f065ea4497eb145f9da9/mounts/shm
tmpfs               1601     0      1601   0% /run/user/1001
```

It said the `/` has still used 36G, and only have 2G space left, why the space didn't get released after over 20G files were moved from original `/` to `/data`?

I was trying to list all directory sizes under `/` but exclude the path `/data` to see what exactly used the space by `du -hsc * --exclude=data | sort -hr` running from `/`:

```
root@iot-message-2001:/# du -hsc * --exclude=data | sort -hr
du: cannot access 'proc/517481/task/517481/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/517481/task/517481/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/517481/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/517481/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/4137254/task/4137254/fd/492': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/4137254/task/4137470/fdinfo/507': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/4137254/task/4137481/fdinfo/519': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/4137254/task/4137511/fd/218': No such file or directory
12G     total
6.1G    var
3.3G    usr
2.0G    swap.img
205M    root
202M    boot
84M     home
76M     titan
5.7M    etc
560K    run
68K     tmp
16K     opt
16K     lost+found
4.0K    srv
4.0K    mnt
4.0K    media
4.0K    cdrom
...
...
```

can see only 12G were used under `/`, and it's suppose to have 28G space left on `/`, but from my testing of by copying a big file(several G) to `/`, the system still say space not enough on `/`, and why is that?

Comment: I'll suggest applying security fixes & upgrades asap, as your indicated details show you've not applied any since before August-2022.   (Refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ which shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded weeks before that date)

Comment: Did you empty trash? And do you have partitions on sdb or did you just format it? Better to have partitions and use gpt partitioning. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR

Comment: @oldfred updated to include the `partition` anf `format` details.

Comment: If you moved or deleted files that are still in use by some process, that space isn't freed up until the process lets go or is killed. You can run `sudo lsof | grep deleted` to see if you have such files and how much space they take.

Comment: While not related to space issue, you show sdb not sdb1  as /data?

Answer (score 0):

after `reboot` the system, the space came back.